# Jmeter recording using Https script recorder

Tags: jmeter

I have tried to use Https test script recorder to record steps and I have verified that I have set proxy too in Firefox. I couldn't get any recordings. Tried the same action via chrome plugin blazemeter and I was able to get the recording steps.

Comment: What do you mean "I couldn't get any recordings." You do actions in browser but nothing happen in JMeter? Or you see any errors?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to set up JMeter certificate. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54303781/5938853

Also check  [JMeter Recording Guide](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/01/jmeter-recording/)

Comment: I have verified the certificate also. The jmeter version I use is 5.1